# Permutation and Symmetric Polynomials

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory

Given a polynomial $f(x_1, · · · , x_n) ∈ F[x_1, · · · , x_n]$ and a permutation
$σ ∈ S_n$, I want to show that both
$\prod_{σ∈Sn}
{σ · f(x_1, · · · , x_n)}$ and $\sum_{σ∈Sn}
{σ · f(x_1, · · · , x_n)}$ are symmetric polynomials.

I know a symmetric polynomial is a polynomial $F(X_1, …, X_n)$ in $n$ variables, such that if any of the variables are interchanged, one obtains the same polynomial. Or P is a symmetric polynomial if for any permutation $σ$ of the subscripts $1, 2, ..., n$ one has $F(X_{σ(1)},…, X_{σ(n)}) = P(X_1,…, X_n)$. But I am not sure how to proceed in the above example.

Comment: You can't say "given a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$" and then sum over $\sigma\in S_n$.

Comment: Hint: for each $\tau \in S_n$, multiplying by $\tau$ on the left is a permutation of the group $S_n$. (the proof of Cayley's theorem). This is a common trick in group theory, averaging over a group.

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial $g$ is a symmetric polynomial if $\sigma g=g$ for all $\sigma \in S_n$.
For your case we have $g=\sum\limits_\tau \tau(f)$. If $\tau$ runs over $S_n$  then the  set $\sigma \circ \tau$ coincides with $S_n$.Then 
$$
\sigma(g)=\sum\limits_\tau \sigma(\tau(f))=\sum\limits_\tau (\sigma \circ \tau)(f)=\sum\limits_\tau \tau(f)=g,
$$
so $g$ is an symmetric polynomial.

Comment: Ah how about the case for product rather than sum? Is the proof the same?

Comment: yes, the proof is the same